# Jquery validation

Tags: jquery

I am using the below code to validate a user's input:

```
function validateAddress(){
//if it's NOT valid
if(f1.val().length = 0){
f1.addClass("error");
return false;
}
//if it's valid
else{
//whatever
}
```

My  question is: For the user to fill his address I have 3 text_fields. id=f1 - id=f2 - id=f3. In this line

```
if(my_text_field_id.val().length = 0){
```

Can I check if any of these values (f1, f2, f3) are empty? (not just one at a time)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your html:

```
<form id="target" action="">
  <input type="text" id="f1" />
  <input type="text" id="f2" />
  <input type="text" id="f3" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

and your script would be:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form').submit(function(){
      if($('input:text[value=""]').length == 0){
          return false;
      }
  });
});
```

basically using the following jquery selector will select all empty text input

```
$('input:text[value=""]')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("form").submit(function() {

    // get the collection of empty text fields
    var empty = $("input[id^='f']").filter(function() {
        return this.value == "";
    });

    // add the error class to them
    empty.addClass("error");

    // submit if there are no empties (return false prevents submit)
    return !empty.length;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The form markup goes like this:

```
<form id="target" action="destination.php">
  <input type="text" id="f1" />
  <input type="text" id="f2" />
  <input type="text" id="f3" />
  <input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Validation checks all empty fields in the form(uses jQuery):

```
$(function() {
  $('#target').submit(function() {
    var flag = true
    $("#target input[type='text']").each(function(index){
      if($(this).val().length == 0) {
        flag = false;
      }
    });
    return flag;
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes... Form is like that but in there, there are more fields that are validating with other rules... I need to modify the validation script (if is possible) because I cannot select the form id... I need to check if empty only those 3 fields in my form.

Comment: Add the address fields (f1,f2,f3) inside a DIV and give it some ID (say, mydiv). Then replace $("#target input[type='text']") with $("#mydiv input[type='text']")